# Is not it possible to create an OS X screensaver in Xcode 9?

Tags: xcode, macos, screensaver

Recently I was interested in screensavers. And while I was looking for a way to write it, I found that it was supported by Xcode.

[image]

ref: https://whichline.wordpress.com/2015/07/13/os-x-screensaver-swift-2-part-1/

But my Xcode 9 does not seem to support screensaver project.

There are no way to write screensaver on Xcode 9?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Screen saver is listed for me on Xcode 9.2, in the "Other" section:

[image]

Comment: oh my.. I could not fount id because I created it as a new file. But 'new project', the I can found it. Thanks.